# Calling template member function of template class fails on GCC/clang but works with MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, g++, clang++

I am trying to wrap a call to a template member function of a template class with a free function, and I do not understand why the snippet of code below compiles with MSVC but is rejected by gcc and clang.

```cpp
template <int N>
struct S {
    template <int I>
    void f();
};

template <int N, int I>
void call(S<N>& s) {
    s.f<I>();               // g++-9.1 and clang++-8.0 complain here
}

template void call<4, 1>(S<4>&); // The exact numbers are unimportant
```

This code fails to compile with g++, with the error message `error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator<'`.
Clang similarly refuses to compile this, complaining `error: missing 'template' keyword prior to dependent template name 'f'`.

MSVC happily compiles the full example with no errors or warnings.

Is this code valid C++ or are gcc and clang correct to reject it?

Comment: `s.template f<I>` will do the trick.

Comment: You need to call it as `s.template f<1>()` because it's a dependent name.